# Norm of sum of vectors equals difference of norms.

Tags: linear-algebra

> When does $||u+v|| = ||u||-||v||$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$?

So I tried squaring both sides (because both sides will be non-negative), so we get that

$$||u+v||^2 = (u+v) \cdot (u+v) = u \cdot u + v \cdot v + 2 (u \cdot v)$$
$$(||u||-||v||)^2 = u \cdot u + v \cdot v - 2(u \cdot v) $$

So we get $2(u \cdot v) = -2 (u \cdot v)$, which holds iff $u \cdot v = 0$, so the vectors must be orthogonal.

Is this correct or am I overlooking something? I'm especially unsure about squaring, I'm not sure if that is really required here.

Comment: $||u||-||v||$ is not necessarily non-negative, so the requirement $||u||\geq ||v||$ is needed for that to be true. This can be made sure of by taking the absolute value for instance.

Comment: Also, $-2||u||||v||\neq -2u\cdot v$ in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a minor mistake

$$(||u||-||v||)^2 = u \cdot u + v \cdot v - 2||u|||| v|| $$

$$u.v = - ||u|| ||v||$$

$$\implies u=-kv$$

where $k \geq 1$.

Substitute to the original problem to check the solution